# Convert cURL into Retrofit function (GCM notification push)

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging, retrofit

Im trying to convert my cURL for GCM notification push into Retrofit function, but I dont know exactly how.
My cURL look like this:

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=KKK" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"XXX\"]}"
```

where KKK = key, and XXX = userRegistrationToken.

Im missing message there, because I didnt find how to do that, but in general this cURL works. I want to make exactly same thing but with (notification) message.

I tried and got something like this:

```
//GCM_ENDPOINT = "https://android.googleapis.com";
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/gcm/send")
    void sendNotification(
            @Header("Authorization") String key,
            @Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
            @Field("message") String message,
            Callback<Object> response);
```

I dont know if this so far is correct, but well it lacks that notification message I want to send, and I dont even know how to deal with this **-d registration_ids** especially when I want to put few of ids there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a solution, even tho its not really by directly converting that cURL, it does work perfectly:

```
@POST("/gcm/send")
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
void sendNotification(
        @Header("Authorization") String apiKey,
        @Body TypedInput jsonBodyInput,
        Callback<NotificationResult> response);
```

Where **NotificationResult** is my custom gson class, and **apiKey** has to be with "key=" prefix (example: String apiKey = "key=" + "XXX";). Also, important thing is to make **jsonBodyInput** as TypedInput like this:

```
TypedInput requestBody = new TypedByteArray("application/json", jsonString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

How **jsonString** might look like you will find [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#common-message-options)